# Regex match word boundary with quotes

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a string within the word boundary.

```
preg_match('/\bTORUK Cirque du Soleil\b/ims',
           'Show: TORUK Cirque du Soleil with Lady Gaga', $matches);

Output: TORUK Cirque du Soleil
```

This works perfect. But when there are quotes in the string it doesn't work as expected. For example,

```
preg_match('/\bTORUK "Cirque du Soleil"\b/ims',
           'Show: TORUK "Cirque du Soleil" with Lady Gaga', $matches);
```

It doesn't match at all. Expected output in this case is `TORUK "Cirque du Soleil"`.

Tried using `\B` i.e. non-word boundary, but breaks in strings where there are no quotes.

Have created a [fiddle here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=106593).

Comment: Quote manual: _“A word boundary is a position in the subject string where the current character and the previous character do not both match \w or \W (i.e. one matches \w and the other matches \W)”_ - with `"[space] ` you don’t have that.

Comment: That's right, in case of double quotes word boundary doesn't fall in. Any work around for these type of cases?

Comment: Why are you using `\b`? it's not a word boundary.

Comment: Why do you need `\b` here at all? Do you expect sth. like `ABCTORUK` ?

Comment: I'm using word boundary to prevent sub-string from being matched. E.g. if the string is `ShowTORUK Cirque du Soleil with Lady Gaga`, it shouldn't match in this case.

Comment: Look for lookarounds instead of word boundaries `preg_match('~(?<!\w)$str(?!\w)~', ...);`

Comment: So `TORUK "Cirque du Soleil"` and `TORUK Cirque du Soleil` should match? At what point can there be quotes, only before `Cirque` and after `Soleil`?

Comment: @user3783243, It's a sample string. There can be any variation of it. Position of quotes is not fixed. Quotes may or may be not present.

Comment: @revo, lookaround is working. Can you please explain what `(?<!\w)` and `(?<!\w)` do ?

Comment: The former is a negative lookbehind that ensures there is no preceding *word character* and the latter with no `<` at beginning ensures there is no following *word character*. You may change them to `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` if you mean the `$str` shouldn't be preceded or followed by any non-whitespace characters and not just word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Comment: @Samir Can you show how you used the looks? With your 4 examples that should match I can't get it to function as you described still. https://regex101.com/r/9Ea96M/1/

Comment: @user3783243 You used two `(?<!\w)`. One should be `(?!\w)`.

Comment: @revo  Ah, Thanks... and it looks like the demo has a typo in it both `Times Presents: TORUK Cirque du Soleil with Lady Gaga` is suppose to match and not match. I guess it was just supposed to match.

Comment: @revo, thanks for the lookaround solution :)

Answer (score 0):

First, as @misorude pointed out, you need to specify proper delimiters, e.g. `/`.  Second, you can specify to match a word boundary or a quote - something like this:

```
preg_match('/\bTORUK "?Cirque du Soleil("|\b)/',
           'Show: "TORUK Cirque du Soleil with Lady Gaga"', $matches);
```

Note that this deals with the specific example you provided and you may need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: There is an example link in my post with set of different examples. Can you please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (and shouldn't use) the `\b`.
You have a sentence not a word.

```
preg_match('/TORUK "Cirque du Soleil"/ims',
       'Show: TORUK "Cirque du Soleil" with Lady Gaga', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "TORUK "Cirque du Soleil""
}
```

---

To answer your comment.
Use word boundry on the first and last word only:

```
preg_match('/\bTORUK\b "Cirque du \bSoleil\b"/ims',
       'showTORUK "Cirque du Soleil" with Lady Gaga', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

https://3v4l.org/bIW4i

Comment: Need word boundary to prevent sub-string from being matched. E.g. if source string is `ShowTORUK "Cirque du Soleil" with Lady Gaga`, it shouldn't match.

Comment: @Samir See update

Comment: Thank you for the update. Really appreciate all the help. It matches if last word is a substring, like `show: TORUK "Cirque du Soleil"with Lady Gaga`